# How to play audio file retrieved as blob file in php?

Tags: php, audio, blob

I want to play the audio file while is retrieved from the mysql database as blob file in php. But when i run the file, the php file is downloaded.

Here is my code

```
<?php 
   $file_path = "H:\\uploader\\John.mp3";
?>
<audio src="<?php echo $file_path;?>" preload="auto" />
```

can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing any examples of what you're tried with mysql, but maybe this will point you in the right direction:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php

Edit:

Try including the embed element:

```
<?php 
   $file_path = "H:\\uploader\\John.mp3";
?>

<audio controls>
  <source src="<?php echo $file_path;?>" type="audio/mpeg">
  <embed height="50" width="100" src="<?php echo $file_path;?>">
</audio>
```

Comment: im having the file in local folder and try to play but it is downloading the php file